# Mysql PHP связанные выпадающие списки марка-модель

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, redbeanphp

Нужно связать 2 таблицы в 2-х выпадающих списках `<option value>`

Таблицы:

1. `mark`  содержит поле `id` (цифра) и поле `title` (марки наподобие Porsche)
2. `model` cодержит `id` (цифра), `title` (модели наподобие Cayenne), `mark_id` (цифра сопоставляется с `id` из таблицы `mark`)

Нужно чтобы при выбора марки из таблицы `mark` автоматически подгружались модели из таблицы `model` при этом таблицы все начинаются с `id` 1.

То есть совпадения должны быть между таблицей `mark(id)` и таблицей `model` (`mark_id`) и если они есть, показываются все модели из `title`.

Список должен автоматически меняться если выбирается другое значение.

Использую также `Redbean PHP`.

Ниже привожу код, в котором должны появляться значения.

Марки

```
<select class="select2" name="mark" id="mark" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Выберите марку</option>
    <option value="0">Все марки</option>'
    <?php if (isset($marks)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($marks as $mark): ?>
             <option value="<?=$mark['id']; ?>"><?=$mark['title']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

Модели

```
<select class="select2" name="model" id="model" required>
   <option value="0" disabled selected>Модель</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

В начало страницы:

```
if ($_GET['mark']) {
    $model = R::findAll('model', 'ORDER BY title ASC WHERE `mark_id` = ' . $_GET['mark']);
    print json_encode($model);
}
```

HTML, JS

```
<select class="select2" name="mark" id="mark" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Выберите марку</option>
    <?php if (isset($marks)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($marks as $mark): ?>
             <option value="<?=$mark['id']; ?>"><?=$mark['title']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
</select>
</select>

<select class="select2" name="model" id="model" required disabled>
   <option value="0" disabled selected>Модель</option>
</select>

<script>
    const mark = document.getElementById("mark"),
          models = document.getElementById("model");
          
    mark.addEventListener("change", () => {
      fetch("http://myweb-stie.com/?mark=" + mark.value)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let children;
        while(children = models.children[0].nextElementSibling) {
          models.removeChild(children)
        }
        models.value = 0;
        models.disabled = false;
        data.map(model => {
          const option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = model.mark_id;
          option.innerText = model.title;
          models.appendChild(option);
        })
      })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый отклик. В командах Js и Java вообще не секу. Можно объяснить как это все привязать в моем случае к моим страницам PHP?  fetch("https://example.com/api/getModel/" + mark.value) чем это заменить?

Comment: @Eric7777777 можно заменить на `fetch("example.com/?mark=" + mark.value)`
смысл не меняется. главное вернуть данные с базы в формате JSON.

Comment: Мне нужен код, который будет работать автономно только от моих Баз данных, а не от сторонних сайтов example.com Все марки и модели их список находятся у меня в таблицах.

Comment: @Eric7777777 оО надеюсь, что вы это не серьёзно. это не сторонний сайт а простой текст - шаблон на место которого нужно подставлять свой сайт.

Comment: Я просто новичок в сфере.                                                          
                                                                                                                      
    <option value="1">Марка 1</option>
    <option value="2">Марка 2</option>
    <option value="3">Марка 3</option>                                                                    
         Эти пункты заполнять нужно вручную???   А через php код это сделать нельзя, чтобы было автозаполнение полей марка?  Объясните пожалуйста разницу, если делать через PHP и вашим способом?

Comment: Сейчас вставил код, БД подключены, ссылку на сайт исправил на свою, список не открывается моделей.

Comment: @Eric7777777 в метках `AJAX` и `JavaScript` указаны были для красоты? если хотите что бы всё сделали за вас, то дополните ответ полным `PHP` кодом. Вручную заполнять ничего не нужно.

Comment: @Eric7777777 `PHP` код был закомментирован для показа работоспособности непосредственно на `StackOverflow`. раскоментируйте его и всё успешно "само" заполнится.

Comment: Я скопировал код, расскоментировал строки PHP. Указал ссылку на сайт и страницу (https://myweb-stie.com/Index.php ), где исполняется скрипт JS.   Теперь не показывает вообще ничего в марках.   Что делать с этой строчкой? 

const fetch = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const data = [
            {id: 1, title: mark.value + ". Model 1 "},
            {id: 2, title: mark.value + ". Model 2 "},
            {id: 3, title: mark.value + ". Model 3 "}
        ];
        data.json = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(data));
        resolve(data);
    })
}

Comment: Марки вывел, модели пока не хотят $marks = R::findAll('mark', 'ORDER BY title ASC');  Таким же образом включил модели, но не выводит их.

Comment: @Eric7777777 обновил ответ

Comment: webDev_   Спасибо, но к сожалению чуда не произошло... Выводит марки, модели пустые. Если честно совершенно не знаю что делать. Здесь всего 2 значения кода, как люди сотни зависимых списков создают...

Comment: @Eric7777777 забыл про вывод. дополнил. Таблица `model` состоит из `mark_id` и `title`?

Comment: Спасибо, но пока все также. Таблица model cостоит из трех полей,  id, title, mark_id    Таблица mark состоит из id и title. Соответственно сравниваем из таблицы mark поле id с полем mark_id в таблице model.